# Running excel macros only on one sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Hi Iam new to writing VBA code and need assistance. My VBA code and Macro works fine as long as I am on the active sheet.

**My Problem:** 
My VBA code and macro, stops running automatically, when i change from the active sheet to another within the same workbook and
My VBA code and macro, stops running automatically, when i open a new excel workbook

**Solution required:**
Run the VBA code and macro only on desired worksheet and prevent it from running on other worksheets and workbooks.

**Background:**
I have an excel file, named "Net Weight" with two sheets. sheet 1 is named : "weight", sheet 2: is named "base data".
sheet 1 is used as a user input form.

In sheet 1- cell B1 : user will type in a product code , in cell E1: a look up formula will place the description of the product code using the data from sheet 2

I have setup a VBA code and macro that does the following:

1. As soon as a user inputs a product code into cell B1, in sheet 1, sheet 1 is saved as PDF file into a predefined folder location data from cell B1 and E1
2. A macro saves and overwrties the PDF file every 10 seconds.
3. This process is repeated every time a new product code is entered

There are no buttons on sheet 1, everything is done automatically.

Here is my current code:

Sheet 1: set as Worksheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then
        Call Macro1
    End If
End Sub
```

Module 1 macro : set as general

```
Sub Macro1()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If ThisWorkbook.Name = "Nett Weight.xlsm" And ActiveSheet.Name = "Weight" Then
        Sheets("Weight").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:="C:\Nett weight\" & Range("B1 ").Text & Range(" E1").Text
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "Macro1"
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should restore `DisplayAlerts` before exiting *Macro1*

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create a public variable to hold your timer, otherwise you'll never be able to cancel it so it will continue trying to fire even when your workbook is closed.  You should also create a public variable to store when the timer is running, so you can check before creating a new timer.

At the top of a **code module** put:

```
Public nextTime As Date
```

Then in your Workbook_BeforeClose() event method (within ThisWorkbook), disable the existing timer so it doesn't keep trying to fire after the workbook is closed.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    On Error Resume Next   ' Continue with next line of code if we encounter an error
    Application.OnTime Earliesttime:=nextTime, Procedure:="Macro1", Schedule:=False
    On Error GoTo 0   ' Resume error-trapping

End Sub
```

In `Macro1()` you should explicitly and directly reference your workbook components - `ThisWorkbook` always refers to the workbook the code is running from, so you don't need your `If` statement.  Then you set the `nextTime` and activate the timer using that variable if it is not already running.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim sht As Worksheet   ' Creates a variable to hold your Weight worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weight")   ' Sets the reference

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    sht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\Nett weight\" & sht.Range("B1").Text & sht.Range("E1").Text   ' Remember to preceed Range with sht. to explicitly reference the range of your Weight worksheet

    On Error Resume Next   ' Continue with next line of code if we encounter an error
    Application.OnTime Earliesttime:=nextTime, Procedure:="Macro1", Schedule:=False
    On Error GoTo 0   ' Resume error-trapping

    nextTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)   ' Adds 10 seconds to Now
    Application.OnTime Earliesttime:=nextTime, Procedure:="Macro1", Schedule:=True
    timerIsRunning = True

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True   ' Remember to enable alerts at the end of code

End Sub
```

Your Worksheet_Change() event method can stay as is.  Now if there is a change in B1 it will call Macro1().  Macro1() will save the Weight worksheet as a PDF regardless of whether the workbook or worksheet is active, and create a new timer to re-run Macro1() every 10 seconds after deactivating an existing timer.  When you're finished with the workbook, you close it and the existing timer is also deactivated.

**EDIT:**

Fortunately (as it fixes a spreadsheet of my own) I have figured out why the solution I originally provided wasn't working.  Placing the `Public` variables under `ThisWorkbook` meant they no longer held their values after code execution.  The remedy was to place them in a module instead.  Once that was sorted out, I also realised that when the timer fires to call `Macro1()` it will throw an error when trying to unschedule the existing timer (as none exists unless `Macro1()` was called ad hoc by the `Worksheet_Change()` event).

Long story short: `Public` variables have been moved to a code module, and the `timerIsRunning` flag has been removed entirely and errors when attempting to unschedule the timer are simply ignored in the event that no timer exists.

Comment: Thank you for the code, it works mostly well as required, however during testing I have noticed this error.

Comment: Thank you for the code, it works mostly well as required, however during testing I have noticed 2 situations I would like to correct.
 1. When I open a new workbook while the "Net Weight" workbook is open, the screen switches back to the "weight" sheet in "net weight" workbook every 10 seconds and returns back to the new workbook. 
2. While a new workbook is open, upon closing the "net weight" workbook, excel automatically reopen the "nett weight" workbook and begins to save the active sheet as pdf, with existing data in B1 & E1, without user input. Appreciate any further assistance

Comment: @crismelb: Have you entered the code to deactivate the timer in the Workbook_BeforeClose() method?  The reason it's re-opening the workbook is because the timer is continuing to run even after you close it, so long as Excel is still open.  This shouldn't happen if that code is there.

Comment: @crismelb: It seems you want to create a PDF when the value in B1 is changed.  Is it necessary for it to keep doing it every 10 seconds?

Comment: I would like to save the "weight" sheet periodically, so as a user inputs data on a regular basis it saves automatically, without having the user needing to remember to save the file. Note: It doesn't have to be every 10 seconds though.

Comment: Workbook_BeforeClose() method code is in ThisWorkbook   section. As "General" statement I have - Public nextTime As Date
Public timerIsRunning As Boolean. As "Workbook" I have: two private subs. 1 for Workbook open and 2 for workbook close

Comment: Is there a way to send or attach the actual excel file for you to see ?

Comment: @crismelb: See my edit above - I've adjusted my answer to fix the problem of the workbook opening itself up again (it wasn't deactivating the timer as I thought it should).  The issue you have with it flicking back to the workbook whenever the macro runs is probably something you can't get around without changing your requirements.  You can use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to stop it from visually flicking to the other workbook, but it will still run the macro and therefore be disruptive.

Comment: @crismelb: If you're happy for it to *only* run when the user changes cell `B1`, then get rid of the timer altogether and just run `Macro1()` on the `Worksheet_Change()` event.  If you really want it to save changes periodically on a timer you could disable the timer on the `Workbook_Deactivate()` event (like in the `Workbook_BeforeClose()` event) and re-enable it on the `Workbook_Activate()` event, so it only runs when the workbook is being used and not when another workbook has focus.

Comment: Brilliant !!! thank you. Application.ScreenUpdating = False also works.

Comment: @crismelb: Remember to put `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end of your code segment.

Comment: when running this code on windows 10 and Excel 2016, I encountered 2 issues. 1. when I open a new excel file and have this as active sheet, while Nett Weight file is running in the background, screen switches between the two files during auto save. 2. when i open a new excel file which has a macro of its own, i get a run time error. "method on time of object_application failed. These errors did not occur in excel 2013.